# How to stop Spacemacs from asking for a required layer installation

Tags: spacemacs

Each time I open a `.toml` file I'm asked in the minibuffer:

> Support for toml-mode requires installation of layer rust, do you want to install it? (y or n) n

How can I stop that question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You have to learn how to ask Emacs questions.

I didn't know the answer to your question when I first read it.  However, Emacs revealed the answer after I asked it some questions.

- Usually, behaviors are controlled by variables.
- To ask Emacs about variables, you hit <kbd>C-h v</kbd>.

  - The Spacemacs alternative is <kbd>SPC h d v</kbd>.  (Same thing.)
- Then I typed "spacemacs installation", and I got an autocompleted list of some likely candidates.

  - `dotspacemacs-enable-lazy-installation`
  - `dotspacemacs-ask-for-lazy-installation`

After reading their docstrings, I figured out that you have to do this:

```lisp
(setq dotspacemacs-ask-for-lazy-installation nil)
```

### Remember to ask Emacs first.

The more you learn how to ask Emacs questions about itself, the faster you'll get good at it.  Here are a few more to commit to memory.

- C-h f :: describe function
- C-h k :: describe key binding
- M-x ielm :: start an Elisp REPL

Emacs can tell you so much about itself if you ask.

Comment: Quite valuable. Thank you.

Comment: Nice answer! One twist is to be able to disable lazy installation prompt for a specific layer but I guess that might not be possible?

Comment: @JurajMartinka That seems a little too specific to be controlled via configuration.  Maybe something extremely hacky like making Emacs forget that toml-mode even exists could do it, but I feel like it's not worth the trouble.